# Integrating op-amp not understood

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, simulation

I am trying to use an integrating op-amp. What I want to do is apply + 0.5 V for 40 us and afterwards apply -1 V for 20 us.

Since the integration sum over one period is zero,  thus if my reasoning is correct the DC offset should be zero as the capacitor is not storing charge over one period.

However, in the simulation the result is different.

What is the conceptual mistake I am making?

[image]

Comment: Crop the screen-grab, man. <20% of it is useful.

Comment: done @Transistor

Comment: Only simulate up to 1000 us and make sure that the timestep is 1us or less, delay the first pulse a bit like 10 us so we see should see we start with a trace at zero Volt for 10 us (and if it is not zero, that's a clue). Then also plot the current through R9 just to be sure it is it should be.

Comment: @Navaro, but don't crop off the axis labels. How are we supposed to see what the voltages and times are now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is apply + 0.5V for 40us and afterwards apply -1V for 20 us. Since, the integration sum over 1 period is zero. And thus if my reasoning is correct the DC offset should be zero.

Correct in theory.

In practice it is unlikely you will be able to perfectly balance things, so your system will drift over time, until it hits a rail. In general it's not a good idea to use a pure integrator in an open-loop system.

Still that does not by itself explain your problem. If it was drifting out after many cycles that would be a reasonable interpretation but it seems to be going up by twice what it is going down by.

> However, in the simulation the result is different.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with your simulation software so I don't know what the laundry list of parameters you are passing to your voltage sources mean and whether or not they match up with your description. A first glance suggests that they do though.

The next thing I notice is the slew rate of your op-amp. This may distort the pulses after your first stage amplifier but the relatively small voltages mean this affect is hopefully not too significant.

However the slew rate limit has a more significant effect on the integrator itself. With an ideal op-amp the ramp rate of an op-amp integator is

$$-V_{in}\frac{1}{rc}$$

The first stage of your circuit is also inverting, so we can cancel the minus sign and get a ramp rate equation for your overall circuit as.

$$(V_{in1}+V_{in2})\frac{1}{rc}$$

So when you apply your 0.5V pulse you would get a ramp rate of 0.5 V/uS and when you apply your -1V pulse you would get a ramp rate of -1 V/uS

The problem is your op-amp can only deliver 0.25V/uS. So the up and down slopes happen at pretty much the same rate, but your up-slope lasts twice as long as your down-slope. So the overall result moves upwards rather quickly.

End result things drift upwards rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Based on your comment,  I feel that I will struggle to balance things in practice. What is a practical way to balance things?  Is it a good idea to check the voltage (with MCU) on the output and switch off the -1V pulse when the voltage becomes zero.  Or can you give any direction ? @peter Green

Comment: You have basically two options for balancing. One is to use some form of feedback (such as having your MCU monitor the output voltage). The other is to add a resistor in paralell with your capacitor so the integrator slowly drifts towards zero (obviously this will distort your wave-shape, whether that distortion is acceptable depends on your application).

Answer (score 3):

Large signal slew rate of LT1001 is about 0,25V/us. All gain will vanish when the frequency (sinusoidal) rises to 1Mhz. You may have knocked your head to the non-ideality of the opamp.

You can test it. Change R9 to 10 kOhm and C3 to 10 nF. Make the input pulses 100 times longer and see if the result is still the same. If it's ok after the changes, then I guessed right.

There's also another hitch. The time constant of the integrator is only 1us. 1V input causes 1V drift in 1us. You can meet the max output (=about 13,5V) too soon. But you cannot see it if the problem is too small slew rate, which prevents the linear operation.

**ADD due the comment:**
You changed R9 and C3. You made the integrator 100x slower. 1 V input causes now only 0,01 V change to output in 1 us.

Slew rate:

The opamp can change its output max. 0,25 V/us and you ask only 0,01 V/us, the slew rate 0,25 V/us is enough.

About 1 us time constant: I have no idea what is your final application. At least this opamp cannot handle it if you apply 0,5 or 1 volt input. Maybe 100 mV input would be better.

Comment: I changed the R9 to 10kohm and C3 to 10nF (without making the pulses longer) and it works. Can you explain a bit more why this is the case? I can not grasp the point of the slew rate you made . And I do need a time constant of about 1us.

Comment: @Navaro it's added to the answer

Comment: if i understand correctly, in the previous case I was asking 1V/us of the op-amp while the op-amp was only able to slew at 0.25V/us?

Comment: @Navaro Right. Get the datasheet and find the output dynamics specs such as slew rate, max large signal peak to peak swing vs. frequency etc... I see you have got a better screenshot. There you see that the rising and falling slopes in the output are approximately as steep regardless of the substantial difference between the input pulse voltages

Answer (score 1):

This Op Amp is not designed for high current of 1K load or high slew rate.

The specs indicate 0.25V/us with >=5K load.

So repeat your experiment with 10x bigger input R and 1/10th the feedback C , namely 10k and 100pF and you ought to see some improvement but still limited by current and dV/dt=V/CRin. Which means 1us in theory but internal compensation reduces that typically to 4us/V or 0.25us/V

So you can now reduce the voltage range of your dual pulse to try to stay within the limitations of this device or include complementary emitter followers inside the feedback loop to buffer the output with some loss in gain margin and thus more overshoot but faster slew rates from hFE

Answer (score -1):

> Since the integration sum over one period is zero

Say what? That's not what I see. You have 5 positive pulses and 5 negative pulses. The first two positive pulses are notably wider than the last 3. So of course you get an increasing "baseline" (period when the input voltage is zero) during the first two pulses.

Or, to put it another way, the integral of your input is not zero. So your offset is not, either.

Comment: The integral of his input is zero, the downslope pulse is half as long but twice as strong. The problem is his integrator can't keep up.